# Install Word on Wine (Linux Mint) with existing key

Tags: ms-word, wine, linux-mint

I switched to Linux (Mint) from Windows (10) a few months back and I am still running dual-boot (Win10 & Linux Mint 18.2).  In an attempt to wean my dependency off Windows, I want to run Wine so I can open Word and view my old Word documents that look completely garbled when open them with LibreOffice Writer.

I have Microsoft Office Suite running on Win10  - is there a way to use the same product key for my Wine version of Word since it's the same computer?  Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered LibreOffice?

Comment: @NieDzejkob yes I have, but when I open an old document that I originally made with Microsoft Word, the formatting is all wrong (particularly if it is a resume that has special formatting such as bullet points, text boxes, line breaks, etc.)